# PAC learning in the convex case with bounded expected risk

Tags: machine-learning, upper-lower-bounds, random-functions

In the context of computational learning theory:

Let $f(w,z): \mathcal{W} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be convex in $w \in \mathcal{W}$ where $\mathcal{W}$ bounded by R. Over $\mathcal{W}$, $|f| \leq C$.

Assuming that $f(w,z)$ is learnable in expectation, therefore exists algorithm B such that when given a sample
$S \thicksim D^{m}, |S| = m > m(\epsilon)$ returns
$w_S$ such that
$$\mathop{{}\mathbb{E}}\limits_{S \thicksim D^{m}}[F(w_S)]\leq \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w) + \epsilon$$

Where $F(w)$ is the true risk.

I need to show that for any
$\epsilon, \delta \in [0,1]$, and
$m \gt m(\epsilon,\delta)$, there exists an algorithm A that given samples
$z_1, ... , z_{m_1}$
the algorithm outputs
$\hat w$ such that
$$F(\hat w) \leq \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w) + \epsilon$$

I also need to provide a sample complexity bound in terms of $m(\epsilon)$ and C.

Here's what I have:

Clearly, $F(w) \geq \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w)$ so $F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w) \geq 0$.

So Markov's inequality can used on the random variable $F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w)$:

$P(F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w) \geq \frac{E[F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w)]}{\delta}) \leq E[F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w)] \cdot \frac{\delta}{E[F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w)]} \leq \delta$

So, with probability $1-\delta$:
$F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w) \leq \frac{E[F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w)]}{\delta} = \frac{E[F(w)] - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w)}{\delta} \leq \frac{\min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w) + \epsilon \cdot \delta}{\delta} = \epsilon$

Thus, $F(w) \leq \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w) + \epsilon$.
Using the assumption about the expectation of the risk, given sample complexity of $m(\epsilon \cdot \delta)$ samples.

So, I showed what was needed. But, My sample complexity does not mention C. This is probably wrong.
I tried replaceing $F(w) - \min \limits_{w \in \mathcal{W}} F(w)$ with $F(w) +C$ and following the same logic, but didn't arrive at anything neat.

Please help!